# How are streams and groups related in Django Channels

Tags: python, django, django-channels

Regarding data binding in Django channels, I don't see how the concept of stream is necessary. Perhaps I am failing to see the big picture here and I hope that someone can point out my misunderstanding.

Let me use an example to articulate my confusion.

I have a Django-based `message` model. I wish to broadcast updates to my client whenever a message is created, updated, or destroyed. So I create two things, a data binding and a demultiplexer.

```
class MessageDemultiplexer(WebsocketDemultiplexer):
    consumers = {
        'message-stream': MessageBinding.consumer, 
    }

    def connection-groups(self):
        return ['message-update']
```

I route my websocket traffic to this demultiplexer through channel routing.

```
route_class(MessageDemultiplexer, path="^/messages/")
```

From what I understand, whenever client is connected, he/she is being put into a group called `message-update`. Thus, if I were to broadcast anything to this group, my clients will all receive a message.

Now, let's take a look at the binding class

```
class MessageBinding(WebsocketBinding):
    model = Message
    stream = 'message-stream'
    fields = ['__all__']

    def group_names(cls, instance):
        return ['message-update']

    def has_permission(self, user, action, pk):
        return True
```

The `model` and `fields` class attributes make sense to me. The group names also seem reasonable because we would want to know which group to broadcast the updates to. The permission is also very self-explanatory. However, I just don't see why is stream necessary in here.

Notice that in `Demultiplexer` class, we explicitly stated that `message-stream` is mapping to MessageBinding, why does MessageBinding need to know this piece of information?

One plausible answer is that stream is used exclusively for client sending websocket message to server to modify a model. But why isn't group enough to accomplish this feat? Why one more layer of abstraction?

Thanks